# Woocommerce как в витрину отсортировать по Новинкам и Скидкам

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Доброго времени суток! Мне нужно в Woocommerce на странице витрины добавить три кнопки. Все - показывает все товары. Новинки - отображаются все новинки и Скидки - все товары по скидке. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно осуществить такую фильтрацию?
Пробовал выводить все через шорткоды на отдельной странице, но мне нужна пагинация. А так же на сайте присутствует переключатель количество товаров на странице, он работает только в витрине.

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать с помощью плагина [WooCommerce Products Filter](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-products-filter/). Вот [демо](http://www.demo.woocommerce-filter.com/). Возможность выбрать товары на распродаже там есть, а чтобы выделить новые товары, надо сначала определиться, что такое "новые". Можно такие товары вынести в отдельную категорию, и с помощью этого плагина её показывать.